# XQuery performance

Tags: xml, performance, xquery

I use stylus studio (with DATA DIRECT)/xQuery to join two xmls files to one( files are converted from CSV to xml first and then joined). 
Customer(header) data read first , then matching transaction data for each cusomer read. (using a loop)
Transaction data is also grouped by transaction date(year). Thisi is done by using distinct function.
Transaction data file is quite large and it is quite slow to process. I'm looking at ways to improve performance.
any help. advice is much approciated.
below is the code used. 
Thanks.

```
(:options:)
declare option ddtek:xml-streaming "yes";
declare option ddtek:serialize "encoding=UTF-8, 
               omit-xml-declaration=no, indent=yes";

(:external variables:)
declare variable $esa-h-converter as xs:string external;
declare variable $esa-t-converter as xs:string external;
declare variable $input-h-data-path as xs:string external;
declare variable $input-t-data-path as xs:string external;


(:main:)
<ROOT_NODE>
  {
    let $heads := doc(fn:concat(
                        "converter:", 
                        $esa-h-converter, 
                        "?file:///", 
                        $input-h-data-path))
                  /DATA_ROOT/CUSTOMER 

    for $record at $primaryKey in $heads

    return
      <TEMPLATE>
        <CUSTOMER>
          <RECORD_COUNT>{ $primaryKey }</RECORD_COUNT>
          <HD_REGION>{ $record/HD_REGION/text() }</HD_REGION>
          <HD_CONT>{ $record/HD_CONT/text() }</HD_CONT>
          <HD_FRDATE>{ $record/HD_FRDATE/text() }</HD_FRDATE>
          <HD_TODATE>{ $record/HD_TODATE/text() }</HD_TODATE>
          <HD_CUSNAME>{ $record/HD_CUSNAME/text() }</HD_CUSNAME>
          <HD_ADDR1>{ $record/HD_ADDR1/text() }</HD_ADDR1>
          <HD_ADDR2>{ $record/HD_ADDR2/text() }</HD_ADDR2>
          <HD_ADDR3>{ $record/HD_ADDR3/text() }</HD_ADDR3>
          <HD_ADDR4>{ $record/HD_ADDR4/text() }</HD_ADDR4>
          <HD_STATE>{ $record/HD_STATE/text() }</HD_STATE>
          <HD_SUBTOWN>{ $record/HD_SUBTOWN/text() }</HD_SUBTOWN>
          <HD_PCODE>{ $record/HD_PCODE/text() }</HD_PCODE>
          {

            let $my-transactions := 
                doc(fn:concat("converter:", 
                              $esa-t-converter, 
                              "?file:///", 
                              $input-t-data-path)) 
                              /DATA_ROOT
                              /TRANSACTION
                             [TR_CONT eq $record/HD_CONT 
                              and TR_REGION eq $record/HD_REGION]
            let $years := fn:distinct-values(
                           $my-transactions
                           /fn:substring(TR_DATE/text(), 1, 4))
            for $period in $years
            return
              <PERIOD>
                <RECORD_COUNT>{ $primaryKey }</RECORD_COUNT>
                <YEAR>{ $period }</YEAR>
                {
                  $my-transactions 
                  [fn:substring(TR_DATE/text(), 1, 4) = $period]
                }              
              </PERIOD>
          }
        </CUSTOMER>
      </TEMPLATE>
  }
</ROOT_NODE>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance typically depends a lot on the individual product and on the specific data, so take all the advice you get here with a grain of salt, and test it yourself before believing it.  I hope that someone more familiar than I with Data Direct's processor will be able to weigh in on your question.  But having said that, several things occur to me that might be worth trying:

- You might try sorting the transactions file by customer first, and then performing the merge.  If the transactions file is long, the sort won't be fast.
- Instead of visiting each record in the main file and finding transactions for it, you might (given a transactions file organized by customer) visit each customer in the transactions file and perform the merge.
- Your inner FLWOR expression is doing two selections across the entire transactions file which involve looking at `fn:substring(TR_DATE/text(), 1, 4)` -- this seems quite likely to defeat almost any XQuery engine's optimizer.  If the engine has built an index on date, then looking at the substring ensures that the query processor can't do a simple index lookup on the value, but must scan all the values in the index (or possibly all the values in the document) for matches.

  Since you say you are creating the XML for both files, I guess you can extract that year substring and put it (redundantly) in a separate element or attribute.  That would make it possible in principle for the XQuery engine to build an index and perform that part of the selection using an index lookup instead of a scan.  (Whether that will help or not with your particular processor, I do not know.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will look at stripping the year off during data conversion. Going through the transaction file is not at option as there could be more than one matching header record for set of transactions. Thanks.